# React component import static json file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am importing a json file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Test1 from './test1.jsx';
import data from './data.json';


class TestWrapper extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Projects</h2>
        <Test1 projects={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestWrapper;
```

which I am then try to use it in:

```
import React from 'react';

class Test1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    var rows = [];
    this.props.projects.map(function(el){
       rows.push(<p key={el}>{el}</p>);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Test 1</h2>
        {rows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test1;
```

this is my data.json

```
{
  "projects": [
    "title1",
    "title2",
    "title3",
    "title4"
  ]
}
```

I am getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: this.props.projects.map is not a function

do I need to parse my json file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but `this.props.projects` will contain the JSON data, so you will need to do:

```
this.props.projects.projects.map
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a projects property inside the json object `{projects: []}`. therefore you have to do this.props.projects.projects.map

Answer (score 1):

Using [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) you can retrieve and assign `projects` value from your json import.

```
import { projects } from './data.json';
```